# Jest cannot find Chromedriver when run through VS Code Debug

Tags: selenium, visual-studio-code, jestjs, selenium-chromedriver

I am using `selenium-webdriver` and `chromedriver` in a Node.js project, started via `jest` (actually, `ts-jest`).

When I run:

```
npx jest test/integration/SetupTest.test.ts
```

The test runs fine. It opens Chrome and connects Selenium to it.

The test setup goes something like this:

```js
import webdriver from 'selenium-webdriver';
let driver: webdriver.WebDriver;
const chromeOptions = new chrome.Options().addArguments(`--load-extension=extension`);
driver = new webdriver.Builder()
        .forBrowser('chrome')
        .setChromeOptions(chromeOptions)
        .build();
```

However, when I use the following VS Code launch configuration:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Debug Integration Tests",
      "program": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js",
      "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
      "args": ["--runInBand", "--no-cache", "test/integration"]
    },
  ]
}
```

The debugging itself fails with:

```
The ChromeDriver could not be found on the current PATH. Please download the latest version of the ChromeDriver from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html and ensure it can be found on your PATH.

      49 |         .setChromeOptions(chromeOptions)
    > 50 |         .build();
         |          ^


      at new ServiceBuilder (node_modules/selenium-webdriver/chrome.js:173:13)
      at Function.getDefaultService (node_modules/selenium-webdriver/chrome.js:212:22)
      at Function.createSession (node_modules/selenium-webdriver/chromium.js:582:49)
      at Function.createSession (node_modules/selenium-webdriver/chrome.js:289:41)
      at createDriver (node_modules/selenium-webdriver/index.js:155:33)
      at Builder.build (node_modules/selenium-webdriver/index.js:662:16)
      at test/integration/setupTest.test.ts:51:10
      at step (test/integration/setupTest.test.ts:33:23)
      at Object.next (test/integration/setupTest.test.ts:14:53)
      at test/integration/setupTest.test.ts:8:71
      at __awaiter (test/integration/setupTest.test.ts:4:12)
      at Object.<anonymous> (test/integration/setupTest.test.ts:40:15)
```

It seems that somehow the `chromedriver` binary that is in `node_modules` is not picked up correctly when the test is started via VS Code.

How can I get it to run the test regardless?

Note that I do not want to install `npm i -g chromedriver` to provide another `chromedriver` executable just for debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the environment by amending the path:

```
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Debug Integration Tests",
      "program": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js",
      "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
      "args": ["--runInBand", "--no-cache", "test/integration"],
      "env": {
        "PATH": "${env:PATH}:${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/.bin"
      }
    },
```